# How to check if a number has occurred a particular number of times in a list consecutively

Tags: python, logic

I am given a list:

```
[1 , 0 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 1]
```

I want to write a program that checks if there exists a number in my list that occurs 5 times (number may vary depending on user input) consecutively and return that number.

In this case the output should be 4.

Are there any predefined functions in Python that solve such problems?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
lst = [1 , 0 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 1]

for number, sublist in groupby(lst):
    if len(list(sublist)) == 5:
        print(number)
```

By default, `groupby()` groups continuous elements based on equality, so it works perfectly fine for you (otherwise, the `key` argument can be provided).

While iterating through `lst`, the `groupby()` function will construct a new sub-list and populate it with all consecutive values equals to each other. If the iterated value differs from the previous one, `groupby()` will yield the `number` with the corresponding `sublist` populated. That is: `(1, [1])`, `(0, [0])`, `(4, [4, 4, 4, 4, 4])` and finally `(1, [1])`. So, you just have to check the `len()` of the yielded `sublist` to verify it contains enough elements. Note that those are not actually "list" but rather "iterable", hence the required call to `list()`.

Comment: can you please explain how this line 
if len(list(sublist)) == 5: work?

Comment: @Viper I tried to add more explanation, but I suggest you to read the documentation which explains it in more depth, and to try to play a bit with this code snippet to better understand how it work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this list comprehension:

```
print([v for i, v in enumerate(lst, 1) if {v} == set(lst[i:i+4])])
```

Output:

```
[4]
```

Comment: This does not satisfy "continuously" requirement.

Comment: @Delgan Then may you please explain to me whats the "continuously" requirement?

Comment: this would even give me output as 4 if my list is like 
[1 , 4, 2 ,4 , 4, 2, 5]
but i want to check if a number is occurring continuously for a number of times?

Comment: Fails when the number in question isn’t an integer >= 0. Example, fails on `[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]`. The OP said “number”, not integer >= 0. The `enumerate` approach isn’t sufficiently general.

Answer (score 0):

`Sliding window` for this problem.

```
def checkList(listi, num):
    k = [listi[0]]
    nk = 0
    listo = []
    for v in listi[1:]:
        if v == k[-1]:
            k.append(v)
        else:
            if len(k) == num:
                listo.append(k[-1])
            k = [v]
    if len(k) == num:
        listo.append(k[-1])
    return listo

l = [1 , 0 , 4 , 4  ,4, 4 , 4 , 1]
print(checkList(l, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y=list(set([x[i-1] for i in range(n-1, len(x)) if x[i-n:i]==[x[i-n]]*n]))
```

Where 
n - number of consecutive occurrences you are looking for 
x - list, which you input 
y - list of elements that occur consecutively n times